# Excel file created using C# is blank and greyed out

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have the below code that creates an excel file.It creates the file perfectly at a given location .However when i open the file.The file is grey-ed out.It does not show any sheet.

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
            return;
        }


        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "One";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";



        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Image Below

[image]

Comment: Where are you adding the Worksheet to the Workbook in your code?

Comment: I tested your code and it did create the file properly. I have version 1.9 (Excel 16.0 Object Library). Which version are you working with?

Comment: @Eriml I also have (Excel 16.0 Object Library).I'm so confused now as to what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following your format, this may get you closer to a solution.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application application = null;
            Excel.Workbooks workbooks = null;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;

            application = new Excel.Application
            {
                Visible = true,
                ScreenUpdating = true,
                EnableEvents = true,
                DisplayAlerts = true,
            };

            if (application == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }

            workbooks = application.Workbooks;
            application.Workbooks.Add();
            workbook = workbooks[1];
            worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
            worksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
            worksheet.Cells[2, 2] = "One";
            worksheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
            worksheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";

            workbook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, AccessMode: Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive);
            workbook.Close(true);
            application.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the file opens during run time and closes.I can see the data in the file flasing but once i open the file its back to square 1.

Comment: Open up the file with excel directly and have look at sheet 1, make sure the values are there in the first three rows and first two columns. If, Sheet 1 is there you should be able to go to the 'View' tab and do what you need to do. This code is written to open the file, add some values and close and save the file, that is why you see it flash open.  Try deleting the file in d:\csharp-Excel.xls and then click the button.  Then open it, should be good to go.